# Where would Heaven be?

Tags: exploration

How could it be explained that living humans have yet to see heaven despite it being depicted as amongst the clouds, when they have technology to see vast distances in to space and have ventured out as far as the moon?

In my story there is a Heaven where people go when they pass, even though a large proportion of people do not believe it exists.

Comment: All my excuses, I'm a bit tired and haven't read you question right (I shouldn't be on worldbuilding in the middle of the night). Sorry again.

Comment: @SpaceLizard Don't worry about it. I might have edited the last part in after you loaded the page.

Comment: We've depicted Earth as the center of the universe and that wasn't exactly right. What makes you think depicting heavens in the cloud means it is right? Not to mention, the Greek variety of heaven is actually down below. Hindus have reincarnation.

Comment: @AmiralPatate I'm not sure what point you're trying to make here.

Comment: That A) religious texts are chokefull of metaphors that aren't meant to be taken literally. Assuming it is even mentioned that heaven is in the clouds somewhere, it doesn't mean it is literally there B) there are a chokefull of religious texts. Some don't have a separate hell and heaven, some don't even have one or the other. Bottomline: you're writing the story, heaven could be literally anywhere, on any plane of existence.

Comment: This question is very broad, currently there is no metric by which to judge answers, there are literally infinite possible answers. Do you want a science answer, or is magic allowed? If magic is allowed, you have to give an explanation of how magic works in your world. Also, what classifies as heaven? How big is it, what is going on that needs to be hidden? There are too many assumptions that have to be made.

Comment: I have heard of the concept of "aether/ether," the mystical "upper air" that deified beings breathe, and sometimes counts as another natural element. It could be said that Heaven exists within a sphere of the atmosphere, made of this high-dimensional quintessence, out of _this_ worlds' reach but can draw in our metaphysical souls, or be ferried by some other force ("The Reaper?"). In the story I'm working on that includes my theory, I like to think that if a camera (of spectacular quality) were to take a video from a rocket as it goes into space, one could freeze-frame on a blurry white scene.

Answer (score 5):

**Heaven is 'above' Earth - if you move in the fourth dimension.**

We haven't seen heaven because we're only capable of moving and seeing in three physical dimensions, but other three dimensional universes exist, separated from ours by some distance in a fourth dimension.

This fourth dimension has a gravity-like force which attracts a soul based on its goodness. It is ordinarily too weak to pull us from the material world, but once we die and our souls leave our bodies, good souls are attracted to heaven, and evil souls repulsed into a region we call hell. We refer to the regions close to the material plane as 'limbo'.

Some souls manage to remain truly neural, and remain in the material soul, where they can interact to some degree with reality. We call these souls ghosts.

Answer (score 2):

Heaven is in the distant future, when we have mastered time travel and use a machine to take snapshots of historically significant human brains at the second before their death.  Capturing every macro and quantum reaction going on in that  moment from long ago, the machine draws the information forward in time to a Utopian city where a freshly manufactured and youthful body is waiting to receive it as a bootstrap for its own consciousness.

Since the information includes every memory, attitude and emotion that was going on when the snapshot was taken, right down to the source's current incomplete thought, the newly booted consciousness doesn't even notice that the hardware of its mind has been changed.

To that new consciousness, the only confusion comes from the sudden change in what their senses are telling them.  They instantly realize that they are in a new and different place, and having been so close to death just a moment earlier, they come to the only obvious conclusion...

"Wow, I've died and gone to heaven!"

Comment: That's a [novel by Spider Robenson](https://books.google.com/books/about/Time_Pressure.html?id=bXNnaBga23EC&hl=en).

Comment: @JDlugosz, Thank you for the reading recommendation!  I love Spider Robenson!  Especially the Callahan series.  Are you sure that this idea is in Time Pressure?   I haven't read it, but the synopsis seems to be running time travel in the other direction.  Rebecca's going into the past.  I'm stealing from the past.  As for my inadvertent stealing of Spider's idea, I will be happy to give him all the credit in gratitude for many wonderful nights of reading.

Comment: If you can, read Mindkiller first.  She goes to her past, it eventually is revealed, as part of a program to "save" everyone who ever lived (not just everyone alive at the time of the singularity), putting a tiny chip in the spine to save the brain state at death, to upload in the future singularity.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much you want to hand wave reality. If heaven does actually exist, you probably have quite a bit of leeway to do so. With that in mind, there are a few possibilities:

1. Heaven is simply on a different “plane” of existence. Whether or not you want to consider this to be a different dimension depends on how seriously you want to try and explain it.
2. Heaven is a parallel or even alternate universe. Perhaps death is a transition from one to the other, with the “heaven” universe having whatever whimsical components you’re interested in.
3. Heaven is actually there in the clouds, but we are incapable of seeing or interacting with it. This gets a little more complicated to explain without hand waved magic, but the location is easier to mentally grasp.

The key, more generally, is to either a) conjure up a location that we physically cannot see / interact with or b) use something akin to magic.

Comment: There is a lot of leeway as there is magic in my story, even if it is usually 'low impact' to the story. For example there are no spells which are more powerful than a sword or a bow.